# Logs on server side for nuxt ssr app not appear

Tags: nuxt.js

Hey I am trying to convert my cache to using Redis.
I created module that get my secret from AWS and update
store.host and store.auth_pass.
I am using ECS to run my servers, after commit my changes to the server every request to the domain is stuck until 504 appear.
I don't know which part of the process is stuck all my logs on server side isn't appear in my cloud watch and when I try to debug the server with vs, they only appear when I run though the terminal.

my module init-redis

```
  // Create a Secrets Manager client
    const client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
      region: region });


    // In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
    // See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    // We rethrow the exception by default.
    try {
      const data = await client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }).promise();

      if ("SecretString" in data) {
        secret = data.SecretString;
        secret = JSON.parse(secret);
        this.options.cache.store.auth_pass = secret.password;
        this.options.cache.store.host = secret.host;
      }
      console.log(`${data}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
```

my nuxt config modules part:

```
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources",
    "@nuxtjs/svg",
    "nuxt-i18n",
    "@nuxtjs/firebase",
    "@nuxtjs/redirect-module",
    "@nuxtjs/sentry",
    "~/modules/init-redis",
    "nuxt-ssr-cache"
  ],

  cache: {
    // if you're serving multiple host names (with differing
    // results) from the same server, set this option to true.
    // (cache keys will be prefixed by your host name)
    // if your server is behind a reverse-proxy, please use
    // express or whatever else that uses 'X-Forwarded-Host'
    // header field to provide req.hostname (actual host name)
    useHostPrefix: false,
    pages: ["/"],
    key(route, context) {
      return route;
    },
    store: {
      type: "redis",
      host: "localhost",
      auth_pass: "XXXXX",

      // maximum number of pages to store in memory
      // if limit is reached, least recently used page
      // is removed.
      max: 1000,
      // number of seconds to store this page in cache
      ttl: 15,
      configure: [
        ["maxmemory", "500mb"],
        ["maxmemory-policy", "allkeys-lru"]
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: k to see logs, in nuxt.config.js we have to  define quiet: false but I still don't know why redis not work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Redis communicate with SSL so I had to change my code to this way:

```
 this.options.cache.store.url = `rediss://default:${secret.password}@${secret.host}:6379`;
```